# onClick event on react component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-dom

I am trying to pass id fro child component to parent component. In the child component the onClick event handler not working. I am trying to log some data to the console on click of an element.

```
import React from 'react';

class EachChatInList extends React.Component {
handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
}


render() {

    return (
        <li className="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
            <div className="circle_m_nested">&nbsp;</div>
            <div className="count"></div>
            {this.props.chat.seller}
        </li>
    )
}
}

export default EachChatInList;
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Your Component works for me as-is: https://codesandbox.io/s/8zo5royj59

Comment: yes, I saw that. But in my case, this is not working.

Comment: In that case the problem lies elsewhere, not within the code you posted. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error in the console

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you're a) clicking the `<li>`s, and b) *not* getting "clicked" in the console?

Comment: yes, I am clicking <li> only and not getting "clicked" message on the console. Is it possible because of something in the parent component onClick is not working in the child component?

Comment: All kinds of explanations are possible. Maybe some other element is covering your `<li>`s and catching the clicks? Who knows? Create a [mcve] and we can help you.

Comment: I have solved the issue. onClick was not working because stopPropagation() was present in parent component and was blocking click event.

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this:

```
onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)}
```

Comment: There's a comment on your question saying it works for someone else. Don't you have a JS error in your console or something not related to this line of code?

Comment: Why do you expect this would help? There is no `handleClick` function in scope to begin with.

Comment: I'm sharing the syntax that would need to be altered on the provided code. He has a `handleClick` function, I'm suggesting the approach I have working on my enviroment to call function on the onclick event @YuryTarabanko

Comment: There  is `this.handleClick` not `handleClick`. "I'm sharing the syntax that would need to be altered on his code." why would OP need to use arrow function?  How this is different from using `bind` in this very case? How would this help?

Comment: True about the handleClick. For my code to work it needs to be a function defined outside of the component. I had issues in the past binding onclick events and this is the approach that worked for me so that is why I am sharing!

Comment: Well, if you declare the function as `handleClick = () => { ... }` then there's no need to bind anything at all. That's not the issue though, OP's code is fine as-is.